# if in_category on archive.php

Tags: archives

So I'm trying to do an if / else statement on an archive.php template. I setting up my archives using WP Smart archives reloaded (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/)

The code from my archive.php is as follows:

```
<?php
   if (in_category('166')) { include 'archive-blog.php';
}

else {
   echo('foo');
}
?>
```

Im trying to get archive.php to include a certain template based on the category number. However this code grabs the archive blog template no matter what (even if I click on a category archive that is not the blog).

I'm wondering if I'm not doing this correctly - does in_category not work on an archive page?  I have a similar set up with a single.php directing to a different include template based on the category.

Thanks!

***Update***

I've also tried to use is_category and it seems to be completely ignoring my first condition and just echoing foo for any category.

```
<?php
   if (is_category('166')) { include 'archive-blog.php';
}

else {
   echo('foo');
}
?>
```

Link to what I'm talking about: (go into the archives in the right sidebar)

http://www.metropoliscreative.com/talent-analytics/w/?cat=166

http://www.metropoliscreative.com/talent-analytics/w/?cat=3

**also, im not using permalinks because the clients server does not have mod-rewrite**

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, in_category() is for use within the loop and returns true when the current post is in that particular category.

You're probably for is_category(166).

Comment: Hi Denis, see my update above. That does not seem to work...

Comment: lol i started to write the answer went answer a phone call and i see your posted answer. your memory serves you wrong  in_category is not only for within the loop.

Comment: lol, depends on how long you tackle with Wordpress: "This tag can be used to test the current post within The Loop or (since Version 2.7) outside the Loop during a single post request." [Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) - and Denis does since a longer time. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could just name your file so that WordPress knows to use it for that category.  According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#What_Template_File_is_Used.3F), WordPress looks for the following files (in this order) in order to display your categories:

1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

So if you named/created a template file called `category-166.php`, then WordPress would use that file to display category 166.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there its not in_category('166') its is_category('166')
the difference are:

- in_category checks if single is in
  that category.
- is_category check if current is that
  category archive page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query- >post;
if ( in_category('166') ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/archive-blog.php’);
} else {
   echo('foo');
} ? >
```

is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try `is_category()` instead.

Example. Check if in category 12 OR 13

```
<?php if ( is_category('12') || is_category('13')) {  ?>

    TEST

<?php }   ?>
```